# How can I create three independent tables on the google sheet where

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

How can I create three independent tables on the google sheet where
I can sort the numbers of each one in an increasing way without affecting the other tables that are on the side.

In MS Excel I can easily do this by creating a table for each one, but in Google Sheet whenever I order the first table it changes the others. that are on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sorts by column C (3) in that range only.

```
function runOne() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange('C2:E10').sort([{column:3,ascending:true}]);
}
```

[Range.sort()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object))